# Regexp to match an XML constellation

Tags: xml, regex, eclipse, xhtml

So I want to match the case where I have 2 times mysubtag within a mytag. So:

```
...<mytag>.....<mysubtag>...</mysubtag>..<mysubtag>...</mysubtag>....</mytag>...
```

where ... are random symbols including newlines.

I don't want to match 2 mytags with each 1 subtag

```
...<mytag>.....<mysubtag>...</mysubtag>....</mytag>...<mytag>.....<mysubtag>...</mysubtag>....</mytag>...
```

Is there a trick to it?

i do the matching in eclipse and what I got so far is:

```
<mytag[\s\S]*?<mysubtag[\s\S]*?</mysubtag>[\s\S]*?<mysubtag[\s\S]*?</mysubtag>[\s\S]*?</mytag>
```

but this matches the second example

**EDIT**
So bottom line: don't use regexp for these tasks
I started a new thread there
[Xpath find files for windows? xml parser to find files in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534160/xpath-find-files-for-windows-xml-parser-to-find-files-in-windows/9534930#9534930)

Comment: Search the site better dude, XML + regexp is poison.

Comment: [\s\S]*? means "space or non-space", which means "everything". (use  .*?)

Comment: You made a slight mistake, you wrote "regex" instead of "xpath" (a mistake that is quite common). A possible XPath expression is "//mytag[count(mysubtag)=2]".

Comment: @sweaver2112 : no, the dot does not match newlines.

Comment: @Toskan: it will if you set the regex options to multiline, which you should be doing if you have newlines in your data.

Comment: @sweaver2112 so you want me to turn on the multiline option in eclipse? well there's no such option there... you can do it in regexp, but then again you cannot turn it back off if you require. Or normally, in the programs i used you cannot turn it back on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using something ***built to parse*** XML, this is much easier. This XPath expression should match the XML constellation you're after.

```
//mytag[count(mysubtag)=2]
```

Comment: Illegal regex syntax. The expression: `[^(?:<\/mysubtag>)]*` does not match what you think it does - hint: it does _not_ match: _"zero or more chars that are not '</mysubtag>'"_ Please go back and review the subject of [regular expression character classes](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). (i.e. It is a syntax error to put a group inside of a char class.)

Comment: @ridgerunner: +1 Thank you for the heads up! Corrected the answer. :)

Comment: @ridgerunner: Out of curiosity, is there any way to do what I was thinking?

Comment: you're assuming there's no other tags whatsoever in his data, but there assuredly are, and they would cause this to not match.

Comment: remove the things about regexp in your answer and i'll accept it eventually. The thing which is still unanswered to me is which tool I can use to say browse all subdirectories of /mfolder/ for occurrences of the xpath expression

Comment: @Toskan: You're trying to do this in eclipse, the editor, not in a specific programming language? Also, you might want to change your question title if you don't want regex answers anymore :)