# Xpath find files for windows? xml parser to find files in windows

Tags: regex, xpath, xml-parsing, file-search

So we have 1500 xhtml pages in lets say 100 subfolders of /myfolder. I want to find evil constellations of

```
<goodTag>
 ....
 <evilTag/>
 ....
 <evilTag/>
 ....
</goodTag>
```

In my current case, it is only allowed to have

```
<goodTag>
....
<evilTag/>
...
</goodTag>
```

and not 2 evil Tags within a good Tag. This is just an example though. Sometimes I must search for something like

```
<outter>
....
<someTag someAttribute="iDoEvil" />
...
</outter>
```

I've been browsing for a while now and could not find a tool which would help me to do so.
What free ware / open source solutions are availble in windows?

What are the xhtml files like? basically they are web pages created for JSF. We use our own tags and keep doing changes to them and thus, have to keep a good eye on bad constellation who haven't been thought of

I'm basically asking because I finally ended up doing it with regex, which makes people around here going nuts.

Comment: Which tag is evil? Why `</goodTag`?

Answer (score 1):

This is a `bash` solution:

- find all xml files in current directory
- list all xml files which contain `<someTag someAttribute="iDoEvil" />`

---

```
for i in `find . -name '*.xml'`
do
    if xmlstarlet sel -H -t -m '//someTag[@someAttribute="iDoEvil"]' -v @someAttribute "$i" >/dev/null
    then
        echo "$i"
    fi
done
```

**Note:** I haven't try to write a `DOS` script in Windows, but the idea is the same.
You can download [`xmlstarlet`(windows version) here](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/download.php).

Comment: Very nice. I didn't know you could do such things with `bash`

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to write your own Java program, you could use a combination of [apache commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io/) and [jOOX](http://code.google.com/p/joox/):

```java
// Use apache commons to recurse into your file structure:
for (File file : FileUtils.listFiles(yourDir, new String[] { ".xml" }, true)) {

    // Use jOOX to parse the file and match the "bad" combination with XPath:
    if ($(file).xpath("//goodTag[count(.//evilTag) > 1]").size() > 0) {
        System.out.println("Match : " + file);
    }
}
```

Note, if you're not up for writing your own program, maybe [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/) might be a better site for this question...